# Django Import Error when running templates

Tags: django, python-2.7, importerror

I am getting this error when I use templates:

```
ImportError: No module named templates.backends.django
```

If I use an `HttpResponse` the page shows up, but I get this error with the `render` function.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def login(request):
    return render(request,'/test.html')
```

I'm using python 2.7.12

Comment: can you show all Django error output

Comment: https://notepad.pw/h8zg1jv2
this is what im getting when i open 127.0.0.1

Comment: OK. Now show please block TEMPLATES from settings.py